# easy way for php function to write to settings file

Tags: php

I have the follwing code writing to a settings file.

```
 $data=json_decode($_REQUEST["data"],true);
 $dbhost=$data["dbhost"];
 $dbuser=$data["dbuser"];
 $dbpass=$data["dbpass"];
 $dbname=$data["dbname"];
 $config="<?php @define('DB_HOST', '$dbhost');
 @define('DB_USER_ID', '$dbuser');
 @define('DB_USER_PASS', '$dbpass');
 @define('DB_NAME', '$dbname'); ?>";

 $fp = fopen("../settings/settings.php", "w");
 fwrite($fp, $config);
 fclose($fp);
```

The settings.php looks like this

```
 @define('DB_HOST', '');
 @define('DB_USER_ID', '');
 @define('DB_USER_PASS', '');
 @define('DB_NAME', '');
```

I would like to replace it with a much easier way to write the empty values since the current code writes the whole file, it doesnt update the values. I know i could use a unique identifier but it is possible to write the empty values instead?

UPDATE :

I also have in that settings.php file some settings based on true or false and this is where i get stuck writing the values.

```
 define('LOGO_IMAGE_PATH', '%logo_image%');
 define('USE_LOGO_IMAGE', true);
 define('SITE_TITLE', '%site_title%');
 define('TRACK_IP', false);
 define('MOBILE_VERSION_ENABLED', false);
```

I couldnt get the function to update the true or false values only if i write the file with the same method like above

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why not JSON rather than trying to write out executable code?  Also, please make sure you are validating your input!  What you are doing is extremely dangerous.

Comment: PEAR Config or libconfigedit would be alternatives.

Comment: well... im still learning php

Comment: possible duplicate of [update config.php with variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152236/update-config-php-with-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You could just save your JSON string to the file, and read the file to parse it out. This is a much safer option than letting users write arbitrary PHP to your server.

Comment: im still learning php...maybe i could get someone to rewrite those functions for me for some cash in exchange ;)

Comment: @dexter4000 this is not a site for hiring developer. However you can visit http://careers.stackoverflow.com and find developers there.